# Queries não devem ser executadas em uma view?

Tags: php

Acabei lendo isso agora pouco "É importante ressaltar que queries não devem ser executadas em uma view. O correto é que você aplique um pattern MVC( Model View Controller) e separe as coisas. Um bom exemplo, utilizando o Framework Code Igniter" Alguém pode me explicar melhor, e qual a diferença de executar a query na view? E se devo mudar meu projeto por conta disso

Comment: voce executa querie na suas views ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme o padrão `MVC` suas queries devem ser executadas pela camada `Model`. O `MVC` é um padrão muito popular e largamente aplicado nos dias de hoje. Ele é um padrão e pode ser substituído por outros.

Contudo é fortemente recomendado que se siga algum padrão, dessa forma caso outra pessoa dê manutenção no seu código terá um pouco menos de dificuldade de entende-lô, e até você mesmo.

Alinhado ao `MVC` é interessante que se siga outras boas práticas de programação, como: [DRY](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), [SOLID](http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2013/04/orientacao-a-objeto-solid/) e outros.

As boas práticas servem para tornar-mos os nossos códigos mais legíveis para humanos, facilitando assim a manutenção e aumentando o ciclo de vida do projeto.

A grande diferença  no lugar onde a query é executada está na organização do projeto.

Quanto a questão de alterar o projeto, creio que apenas você pode responder isso.

Se você tem liberdade para recomeçar o projeto, recomendo a você olhar o [Laravel](https://laravel.com/), que é um framework php que aplica o `MVC`. Recomendo ele pela larga adesão da comunidade e facilidade de encontrar material.